# Select max date in a group where max date is less than current date

Tags: mysql, date, subquery, max

I'm trying to execute a mysql query on this table data that would return the latest date that is less than the current date grouped by the booking number.

Example of the table data:

```
bookingnumber | booking_date |
------------------------------
11            | 2015-02-21   |
11            | 2015-02-22   |
11            | 2015-02-20   |
12            | 2015-02-20   |   
13            | 2015-02-22   |
------------------------------
```

If current date is 2015-02-21 I am striving to get this result:

```
bookingnumber | booking_date |
------------------------------
12            | 2015-02-20   |
```

I have experimented with MAX, subquerys, and groups and this is the "best" I have managed to do so far:

```
"select bookingnumber, booking_date 
FROM table 
WHERE 
(select max(booking_date) from table as f where f.bookingnumber = table.bookingnumber) 
AND booking_date < CURRENT_DATE"
```

This however gives me the result:

```
bookingnumber | booking_date |    
------------------------------
12            | 2015-02-20   |   
11            | 2015-02-20   |
```

Comment: I obviously failed pretty hard on the automated formatting here, trying to fix it, sorry.

Comment: You talk about grouping in the beginning, but then don't want the grouping in the result? I'm not clear why you only want the `12` item?

Answer (score 1):

The following returns the results you are asking for.  It is returning the last date of bookings for which there is no current or future booking date:

```
SELECT bookingnumber, max(booking_date)
FROM table
GROUP BY bookingnumber
HAVING max(booking_date) < CURRENT_DATE();
```

Comment: syntax error: `CURRENT_DATE);` must be `CURRENT_DATE();`